# Recalling raw_input/ input in Python

Tags: python, raw-input

I am trying to create simple quiz using python. Problem occurs when user type in invalid character. Is there any way I can recall the question? The code:

```
count = 1
q1 = raw_input("Question test")
if q1 == "1":
    print ("Correct")
    count = count + 1
elif q1 == "2":
    print ("Sorry, incorrect answer.")
elif q1 == "3":
    print ("Sorry, incorrect answer.")
elif q1 == "4":
    print ("Sorry, incorrect answer.")
else:
    print ("Sorry, invalid input, try again.")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
count = 1
q1 = raw_input("Question test")
sucess = False
while not success:
    if q1 == "1":
        success = True
    ...
    else:
        print ("Sorry, invalid input, try again.")
print("Success ! :) ")
```

You can increment the count when you want. I am not sure what you really want for it.

Comment: Probably a count to track how many correct questions the user got, for scoring purposes. I presume.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably put that code inside a loop. Something like "while answer is invalid ask for input again".

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop to reiterate the question until you are broken out of it, here I have the loop check the value of 1, when an answer is correct/incorrect, it sets it to 0, breaking it out of the loop, and moving on with script execution, if they put in foreign input, it tries the question again, because z will equal 1 still.

```
z = 1
count = 1
while z = 1:
    q1 = raw_input("Question test")
    if q1 == "1":
        print ("Correct")
        count = count + 1
        z = 0
    elif q1 == "2":
        print ("Sorry, incorrect answer.")
        z = 0
    elif q1 == "3":
        print ("Sorry, incorrect answer.")
        z = 0
    elif q1 == "4":
        print ("Sorry, incorrect answer.")
        z = 0
    else:
        print ("Sorry, invalid input, try again.")
```